# Extract one word from String

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am struggling with a REGEX and I can't find a solution.
I have the following strings:

```
LSUS_GDIS_SHIP_0211e947-1587-11de-9967-99f27557554e.txt
LSUS_GDIS_REC_0211e947-1587-11de-9967-99f27557554e.txt
LSUS_GDIS_CAPACITY_0211e947-1587-11de-9967-99f27557554e.txt
```

I need to match each line except SHIP or REC or CAPACITY.

I came up with

```
(?!.*\bSHIP\b|\bREC\b|\bCAPACITY\b).*
```

How can I exclude SHIP or REC or CAPACITY? When I do

```
(SHIP|REC|CAPACITY)
```

I only match these strings but I want to exclude them.

Comment: You may *remove* them with your pattern. Please clarify your scenario.

Comment: Also, please tell us which language or regex tool you are using.  There are more than one way to approach this.

Comment: Hello both, it is a java system but I can't code it myself. I only have the possibility of setting a regex expression and then a "replacement" value. I need to replace everything but SHIP, REC or CAPACITY.

Comment: If the "duplicate" link I provided does not solve your problem, please add more details to your question.

Comment: Replace with what? please show expected outputs on those three lines.

Comment: Try `(SHIP|REC|CAPACITY)?.` to replace with `$1`

Comment: I would split it into two parts: Replace the string before the mentioned words and then replace after the words. Regex for before; `(.+?)(?=((SHIP)|(REC)|(CAPACITY)))` and after `(?<=(SHIP)|(REC)|(CAPACITY)).+` whereas the positive look-behind (`?<=`) may not be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression to match group wise:

```regex
^([\s\S]*?)(SHIP|REC|CAPACITY)([\s\S]*?)$.*
```

Description: For result [check this link](https://regex101.com/r/CSyM3T/1)

- `^` « Matches the start of a string without consuming any characters. If multiline mode is used, this will also match immediately after a newline character.
- 1st,3rd Capturing Groups ([\s\S]*?)

  - `\s` « Matches any space, tab or newline character.
  - `\S` « Matches anything other than a space, tab or newline.
  - `[\s\S]` « match any character
  - `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- 2nd Capturing Group (SHIP|REC|CAPACITY), matches these words as 2nd group
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line

  - `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)

Answer (score 2):

Each line can be broken into three parts with the regex

```
([A-Z_]+)(SHIP|REC|CAPACITY)([_a-z\d-\.]+)
```

Then you can use replacement as

```
replacement1+$2+replacement2
```